# Unable to remove irrelevant floating point value

Tags: r

> Sample of dataset [Full sample can be download via this link](https://www.tworiel.cc/post/2019-04-21-data-cleansing/data-cleansing/data/mooloolaba_2018-01-01t00_00-2018-10-31t23_30.csv)

```
Date/Time,Hs,Hmax,Tp,Tz,Peak Direction,SST
1/01/2018 0:00,-99.9,-99.9,-99.9,-99.9,-99.9,-99.9
1/01/2018 0:30,0.513,0.81,10.315,4.748,-99.9,-99.9
1/01/2018 1:00,0.566,0.93,10.778,5.003,92,26.4
1/01/2018 1:30,0.557,0.85,9.984,4.99,91,26.4
```

> Read in via this method, and all columns except date.time are numeric.

```
maloolaba.waves <- read.csv(file = "./data/mooloolaba_2018-01-01t00_00-2018-10-31t23_30.csv", header = T)
```

> Function to remove rows containing -99.9.

```
maloo.RM.outlier <- maloolaba.waves[!(apply(maloolaba.waves, 1, 
                             function(y) any(y == -99.9) )),]
```

> Now when I do summary after removing value -99.9 I get this.

```
summary(maloo.RM.outlier)

          Date.Time           Hs               Hmax        
 1/01/2018 1:00 :    1   Min.   :-99.900   Min.   :-99.900  
 1/01/2018 1:30 :    1   1st Qu.:  0.805   1st Qu.:  1.350  
 1/01/2018 10:00:    1   Median :  1.112   Median :  1.870  
 1/01/2018 10:30:    1   Mean   :  1.234   Mean   :  2.089  
 1/01/2018 11:00:    1   3rd Qu.:  1.608   3rd Qu.:  2.700  
 1/01/2018 11:30:    1   Max.   :  4.257   Max.   :  7.262  
 (Other)        :14543                                      
       Tp                Tz          Peak.Direction      SST       
 Min.   :-99.900   Min.   :-99.900   Min.   :  5    Min.   :19.80  
 1st Qu.:  7.529   1st Qu.:  5.035   1st Qu.: 91    1st Qu.:21.00  
 Median :  9.146   Median :  5.568   Median :105    Median :23.00  
 Mean   :  9.245   Mean   :  5.679   Mean   :103    Mean   :23.43  
 3rd Qu.: 10.903   3rd Qu.:  6.257   3rd Qu.:119    3rd Qu.:26.00  
 Max.   : 21.121   Max.   : 10.146   Max.   :358    Max.   :28.65
```

Yet when I look at the dataset for maloo.RM.outlier, there are no values -99.9, so I then searched.

```
which(maloo.RM.outlier$Hs == -99.9, arr.ind = T)

[1] 11501 13775
```

I have tried looking at the row numbered 11501 and 13775, no -99.9 values there. I have tried, clearing the global environment data, restarting the R session and nothing seems to fully get rid of the value -99.9 and the summary still says the minimum = -99.9.  Does anyone know how to remove floating point values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/1222578

Comment: Ok, floating point values, yes makes sense, can you please show me how I can isolate the rows.  For instance, sum(maloo.RM.outlier$Hs < 0  ) output [2] yet I can not even find these two negative value.

Comment: `any(abs(y + 99.9) < 1e-9)` should find them.

Comment: @tcratius I like `near` from the `dplyr` package, instead of `any(y == -99.9)` you could do `dplyr::near(y, -99.9)`.

Comment: @r2evans and Marius please make as the possible answer as they have solved my problem.  r2evans, your answer worked better with the apply function however I can see the value in Marius' answer.

Comment: What does this have to do with `Rmarkdown`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [R's FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), you can't really test for floating-point equality, just an approximation. There are several ways to do it, but a popular (and my favorite) way is to subtract my limit/equality and look for something below a threshold.

Because the actual value might be on either side (pos/neg) of my comparison value, we can use the absolute value to take that into account. The resulting code changes your

```
any(y == -99.9)
```

to

```
any( abs(y + 99.9) < 1e-9 )
```

Which, coincidentally, is precisely what Marius' suggested function ([`dplyr::near`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/near.R)) is doing:

```r
dplyr::near
# function (x, y, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) 
# {
#     abs(x - y) < tol
# }
# <bytecode: 0x000000002506d7b8>
# <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

though it is using a slightly more robust way of finding something of just-barely-above a "near-zero" magnitude by using `.Machine$double.eps^0.5`.

I chose `1e-9` for code-golf, though if you are programming something, you should probably name it something meaningful so it isn't a "magic constant". Perhaps `tol <- 1e-9` or `eps <- 1e-9` (for *epsilon*, a variable frequently used to indicate an arbitrarily small, positive number).

Comment: Hi @r2evans, if you would like to download the Maloolaba go to this [link and download](https://www.tworiel.cc/post/2019-04-21-data-cleansing/data-cleansing/) the full Maloolaba sample dataset. I personally found using ```maloo.RM.outlier <- maloolaba.waves[!(apply(maloolaba.waves[,2:6], 1, 
                             function(y) any(abs(y + 99.9) < 1e-9))),]``` worked the best.